# Dynamically change jQuery "hover" by checking cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, cookies

How can I change the function within a jQuery `.hover()` by checking a users cookie?

Right now the code works when the site first loads, but when the cookie is updated (through javascript) the `.hover()` does not switch unless the page is reloaded:

```
    var SkinChk = getCookie('skincookie');

    $('.fadeMenu').hover(function(){
        if (SkinChk == 'Alternative') {
            // Alternative Skin
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(66, 137,170)', color:'#F7F9F4'},500);
        } else {
            // Default Skin
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(255,165,0)', color:'#FFFFFF'},500);
        }
    }, function(){
        if (SkinChk == 'Alternative') {
            // Alternative Skin
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(247, 249, 244)', color:'#1F262A'},500);
        } else {
            // Default Skin
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(201,224,179)', color:'#333333'},500);
        }
    });
```

The `var SkinChk = getCookie('skincookie');` references a working javascript function I didn't post for brevity. It returns the cookie value.

Comment: You should add the code for `getCookie()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're only checking the cookie once, so there's nothing to tell the function to update the SkinChk variable.

The easiest way to fix that would be to move the cookie check inside the hover function:

```
var SkinChk;    

$('.fadeMenu').hover(function(){
    //Check if the cookie has changed
    SkinChk = getCookie('skincookie');
    if (SkinChk == 'Alternative') {
        // Alternative Skin
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(66, 137,170)', color:'#F7F9F4'},500);
    } else {
        // Default Skin
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(255,165,0)', color:'#FFFFFF'},500);
    }
}, function(){
    //Check if cookie has changed
    SkinChk = getCookie('skincookie');
    if (SkinChk == 'Alternative') {
        // Alternative Skin
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(247, 249, 244)', color:'#1F262A'},500);
    } else {
        // Default Skin
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor:'rgb(201,224,179)', color:'#333333'},500);
    }
});
```

You could also create an event that listens to a service which monitors the cookie. Check out [nsICookieService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieService?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsICookieService). I wouldn't reccomend it, though, because it seems like massive overkill for what you're trying to do, but it is an option.

Comment: I knew it was a simple oversight.  I was thinking by calling the variable it would re-define the variable, therefore calling the function again.  But of course that's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to get an updated cookie without reloading the page. Instead of trying to check for the cookie separately from setting the cookie, you can run the javascript that makes the switch WITH cookie setting javascript.